# If $ f(x) $ is injective and continuous on $ I $, then it has no extrema points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I came across the following statement and I need to decide whether it's true or false.

Let $ f $ be continuous on $ I $. If $ f $ is injective, then it has no extrema points.

Can I use the function $ f : \left[2, 2\right] \to \mathbb{R}, \, f(x) = 3 $ as a conterexample.

It's vacuously true that it's continuous, it is injective, and $ x = 2 $ is the extrema point.

Comment: The notion of continuity is a little tenuous for sets with only one point. Also we can nix that case by requiring $I$ to be open.

Comment: $f(x)=3$ is not injective

Comment: The question cannot be answered unless you know more about $I$. For example, if $I$ is an interval and $f$ is continuous, then it is injective iff strictly monotonic. However, that alone neither proves nor precludes extrema points.

Comment: @Cpc their $I$ has only one point

Comment: Oh, I missed that @ArcticChar

Comment: @dxiv that misses the point, a strictly monotonic function over $I$ can only attain extrema at endpoints. An interior point which is an extremum would violate monotonicity

Comment: @MartinGeller You seem to assume that $I$ is an interval, that the interval is bounded (it has *endpoints*), and that it is closed (the endpoints belong to the interval). But neither of those assumptions is given in the question.

Comment: I’m not assuming it, you have stated in your comment “if $I$ is an interval”, and so I replied to your comment. I am not assuming it is bounded, if there are no endpoints, my answer it is true: “ a strictly monotonic function over 
can only attain extrema at endpoints”

Comment: What do you know about continuous functions on compact sets?

Answer (score 0):

This is false under the usual definition of an extremum over an interval (assuming $I$ is an interval), i.e. a value in the interval at which the function attains a minimum or maximum value over the interval. Take for example the function $f(x)$ over [0,1], it attains 0 and 1 as extrema. If you mean an extremum which is not an endpoint, this is a different story. Take a differentiable function, we know by Fermat’s theorem that a non-endpoint extremum the derivative vanishes. If the function is non-constant, there will be a small neighbourhood on the left of the endpoint where the der. of the function will be negative/positive if the extremum is a minimum/maximum, and a small neighbourhood on the right where the der. of the function will be positive/negative respectively. It is obvious that the function is non-injective.

The same argument can be made rigorously and dropping differentiability but requiring continuity.

Comment: The question does not state that $I$ is a closed interval, or even an interval at all.

Comment: $I$ could be a non-topological space and the notion of continuity be an ad-hoc one for non-topological spaces, everything is possible. But the notation chosen and his counterexample are strongly suggestive that it is an interval

Comment: If $I$ is an unbounded real interval, then there are no endpoints, so my question still captures the heart of the matter: non-endpoint extrema are what matters

Comment: I don't see where it's *strongly suggested* that $I$ is a compact interval. Even assuming it's a bounded interval, the statement "*has no extrema points*" is false if $I=[0,1]$ but true if $I=(0,1)$.

Comment: $I$ stands for interval very often inasmuch as we usually write $D^k$ for the $k$-th derivative for an integer and not fractional $k$. I never talked about compactness, only about it being an interval. I insist my argument covers all such intervals, the differentiating factor as to whether it is injective is whether the extremum has been attained on an endpoint

Comment: Which do you propose are the extrema of $\,f(x)=x\,$ on $\,I=(0,1)\,$? Otherwise you can't claim that the statement "*has no extrema points*" is "*false*".

Comment: As I said, if there are no endpoints of the interval, it is still true that “ a strictly monotonic function over  can only attain extrema at endpoints”

Comment: But that's not what OP's question is asking, and doesn't justify your "*this is false*" opening line.

Comment: I didn’t say that it was what the OP’s question is asking, I even prefaced my question with the example of a function over an interval which attains extrema at endpoints. However, I went on to consider interior point extrema which provide a richer discussion

Comment: My initial statement is justified in answering the question in the negative because I provided a counterexample, nothing was specified of $I$ so I could considered a specific example across the possible generality

Answer (score 0):

So, this sort of uses the fact i like that when you draw the graph of a continuous function (on a connected set of course), you don't pick your pencil (or chalk, as the case may be) up.

Intuitively,  if an interior point of $I$ is an extreme point,  then the function either rises then falls on either side,  or vice versa.   So it won't pass the horizontal line test.